# updating ionic 1.5.0 to 1.6.3 causes networking feature not to work - only happens on android

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, rest, ionic-framework

When I upgraded ionic 1.5.0 to 1.6.3 (latest), networking ajax calls does not work anymore. Not sure why. I was required to remove android and re add android platform. not sure but something did change with the apk names from MainActivity-debug.apk to android-debug.apk

This problem only happens on Android but not iOS.

Here is a very simple ajax call:

```
   $scope.doLogin = function () {
        urlcd = "http://desolate-eyrie-5848.herokuapp.com/offsprings.json";
        console.log("XXX:" + urlcd);
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: urlcd,
            timeout: 90000,
            data: {email: email, password: password}//$scope.doLogin
        });

        request.success(function (data) {
            console.log('data: ' + data.status);       
        });
request.error(function (data, status) {
    console.log('XXX error data:' + data + " status:" + status);
});
```

here are my android debug traces:

```
07-30 11:32:18.399: I/Web Console(21850): XXX Doing login  at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js:173
07-30 11:32:18.399: D/PluginManager(21850): exec() call to unknown plugin: Console
07-30 11:32:18.399: I/Web Console(21850): XXX:http://desolate-eyrie-5848.herokuapp.com/offsprings.json at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js:173
07-30 11:32:18.399: D/PluginManager(21850): exec() call to unknown plugin: Console
07-30 11:32:18.459: D/chromium(21850): Unknown chromium error: 0
07-30 11:32:18.459: I/Web Console(21850): XXX error data: status:0 at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js:173
07-30 11:32:18.459: D/PluginManager(21850): exec() call to unknown plugin: Console
```

How can I troubleshoot and get ionic work with networking on Android ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the Whitelist plug-in. Latest versions of Cordova changed how whitelisting works.

http://devgirl.org/2015/04/24/apache-cordova-newsflash/